# C# new TCPClient connection using my IPV6 address fails

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcpclient

This code works with my IPv4 address and fails with my IPv6. How to connect using my IPv6 address?

```
TcpClient whoisclient = new TcpClient(new IPEndPoint(myip, 0));
whoisclient.Connect(serverName, port);
```

Comment: Given that the address is declared as a `Int64`, then the answer is no, at least , not using that method,

Comment: Please let me know, that method then? I can declare address differently, how? Now i enter as a string.

Comment: I have no idea, I don't do C#, I just searched for the TcpClient definition and up it same.